# Why am I getting a Nullpointer exception on trying to set an EditText on a Button click in a Scrollview?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, scrollview

I have a  `ScrollView`  which has a fixed header and footer. I have implemented the `onClickListener`  in my class. I am trying to set a text in the `EditText`  when a Button is clicked. but when I do this I am getting a `Nullpointer Exception`.

My codes are as follows:

contents.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText04"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedittext"
    android:ems="10"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:text="Task 1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="17dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

scrollable_contents.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <!-- Header aligned to top -->

 <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/header"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="70dp"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:background="@android:color/white"  >

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
      android:src="@drawable/propic" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
      android:text="Jack Reacher"
       android:textSize="17dp" 
      android:textColor="#000" />
  </RelativeLayout>

  <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->

 <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/footer"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:visibility="visible"
  android:background="@android:color/black" >

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="160dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="@color/green"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:text="Accept" 
       android:textSize="17dp" 
       android:visibility="visible"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_width="160dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:textSize="17dp" 
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
       android:background="@color/red"
      android:text="Decline" 
       android:visibility="visible"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button3"
      android:layout_width="112dp"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:text="Completed" 
         android:visibility="gone"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:background="@color/green"/>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button4"
      android:layout_width="105dp"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
      android:text="Ongoing"
      android:visibility="gone"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:background="@color/yellow" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button5"
      android:layout_width="105dp"
      android:background="@color/red"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:text="Decline"
      android:visibility="gone"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

  </RelativeLayout>
  <!-- Scrollable Item below header and above footer -->
  <ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/scrollableContents"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_above="@id/footer"
  android:background="@android:color/white" 
  android:layout_below="@id/header" >

   <!-- Inflate the contents of the ScrollView dynamicaly -->

 </ScrollView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

mycontactstemp.java

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // final Databasehandler2 db=new Databasehandler2(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scrollable_contents, container,
            false);
    ScrollView scrollable_contents = (ScrollView)view.findViewById(R.id.scrollableContents);
    View v2 =getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contents, scrollable_contents);
    EditText stat=(EditText)v2.findViewById(R.id.editText04);
     scrollable_contents.addView(v2);
  return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"accept clicked",1000).show();

        stat.setText("Paused");
        /*b1.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
        b2.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
        b3.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);*/
        break;
      }
     }
```

Stacktrace:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime(5223): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime(5223): java.lang.NullPointerException
    E/AndroidRuntime(5223):     at com.example.taskmanager.mycontactstemp.onClick(mycontactstemp.java:106)
    E/AndroidRuntime(5223):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
    E/AndroidRuntime(5223):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
    E/AndroidRuntime(5223):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    E/AndroidRuntime(5223):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    E/AndroidRuntime(5223):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    E/AndroidRuntime(5223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    E/AndroidRuntime(5223):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime(5223):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    E/AndroidRuntime(5223):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    E/AndroidRuntime(5223):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   E/AndroidRuntime(5223):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is line number 106  in `mycontactstemp.java` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `stat` is null

```
EditText stat=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.EditText04)
```

The layout that you inflate is `scrollable_contents.xml`

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scrollable_contents, container,
        false);
```

and you use the same view object to initialize `EditText`.

It belongs to `contents.xml`. Also the id is `editText04` not `EditText04`

And you are calling `setText` on `stat` which is null.

```
stat.setText("Paused");
```

To fix Inflate the layout

```
View v= getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contents, scrollable_contents);
stat=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText04);
```

Finally add this view to the `ScrollView`

```
scrollable_contents.addView(v);
```

Edit:

Change this

```
 EditText stat=(EditText)v2.findViewById(R.id.editText04);
```

to

```
 stat=(EditText)v2.findViewById(R.id.editText04);
```

Edit 2:

I don't know why this is downvoted

Change `scrollable_contents.xml` to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Header aligned to top -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:text="Jack Reacher"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="17dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Accept"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Decline"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Completed"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Ongoing"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Decline"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="visible"  />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Scrollable Item below header and above footer -->

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And `contents.xml` to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText04"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Task 1"
    android:textSize="17sp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Change your Fragment to

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    EditText stat;
    View view ;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scollable_contents, null);

        Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        ScrollView scrollable_contents = ( ScrollView)view.findViewById(R.id.sl);
        LinearLayout v2 =(LinearLayout) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contents, null);
        stat=(EditText)v2.findViewById(R.id.editText04);
        scrollable_contents.addView(v2);

      return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.button1:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"accept clicked",1000).show();
            stat.setText("Paused");
            break;
          }
         }  
}
```

Snap

[image]

Note:

Use `sp` instead of `dp` for `textSize`.

Comment: The app is not getting force closed but my text is not set to paused.

Comment: @user3256145 did you add the view to the scrollview?. If so it will work no doubt

Comment: yes you should. after you initialze and inflate the layout

Comment: @user3256145 where is the button click listeners gone?? No wonder nothing happens although the edit stands.

Comment: my listeners are all there I am getting the toast, I just did not display it in the edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54109/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user3256145).

Comment: @user3256145 there are 2 more problems. 1 ScrollView can have one direct child 2. Your ui is the problem

Comment: Ya Sir, I have gone through google and it tells me that scrollview can have only one child, but I have to use fixed header and footer due to the requirement of the project, and as I have just started coding in Android i don't get exactly what to do. So you putting a downvote is not gonna solve my problem

Comment: @user3256145 you ran away again. pls join the discussion i will post an example. In fact posted another screen shot

Comment: @user3256145 posted a example also. Now this all i can do to help

Answer (score 0):

replace onclick code by,

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"accept clicked",1000).show();
        EditText stat=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.EditText04);
        stat.setText("Paused");
        //b1.setVisibility(v.GONE);
        //b2.setVisibility(v.GONE);
        //b3.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);

        break;
 }
 }
```

Comment: I am not able to use EditText stat=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.EditText04); in onclick as i get an error saying create a variable view. What should I do?

Comment: just define EditText stat globally and put  stat=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.EditText04); in oncreateview()

Comment: this still does not solve the problem bcoz the edittext belongs to a different layout than the one op inflates. `View view` should have been `final View view` its in annonymous inner class

Comment: @user3256145 check my post that should solve your problem. 1. Need to use the inflated view object to initialize edittext. 2. You need to add the view to the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the following mistake,

you have declared `EditText stat` in the top and again you are doing like below,

```
EditText stat=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.EditText04);
```

where as your `onClick` method takes the `stat` from the top which is not initialized. So it shows `NullPointerException`.

To solve this change,

```
EditText stat=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.EditText04);
```

to

```
stat=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.EditText04);
```